# Where did concept of yield keyword come from?

Tags: language-agnostic, yield, yield-keyword

Similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98867/where-did-the-concept-of-interfaces-come-from). Keyword `yield` is present in three languages I know or I heard of: Python, Ruby, C#. They plan to introduce this keyword also to PHP. Where did it originally come from? I did no deep research, but it seems Python has it since 2003, which seems to be before C#.

**Update:** Let's divide this question into two parts:

1. Who invited/introduced the concept of generators? Which language provided the first implementation? When?
2. In which language did the `yield` keyword appeared first? What year?

Comment: The concept has been around for at least 40 years. See [generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_(computer_programming)) and [couritines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)

Comment: @StuartLC I was about to write the same as a answer when I realize you wrote it as a comment. Is there any duplicate to this question? Maybe you could move that comment and make it an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Since generators are a special case of coroutines you would have to credit them to the coroutines creator, Melvin Conway, who proposed them in a paper in 1963. [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)
2. You can get the answer to that question on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29). Over there you will see that LISP have some support through libraries in 1958 but is CLU in 1975 which implemented them natively for first time.